# Will this code leak resources when the coroutine is canceled?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, cancellation

Will the following code leak resources when the Kotlin coroutine is canceled?

General: The code is nested inside a ViewModel!
The method retrievePDFDocument will get triggered in the onStart Event of a Fragment.

```
fun retrievePDFDocument() {
    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            downloadFile(assetPath.value!!)
        }
    }
}
```

And here the suspend function:

```
private fun downloadFile(strPdfUrl: String): File? {
    var inputStream: InputStream? = null
    val lenghtOfFile: Int  //lenghtOfFile is used for calculating download progress

    //this is where the file will be seen after the download
    var fileOut: FileOutputStream? = null
    var localPDFFile: File? = null

    if(strPdfUrl.isBlank())
        return localPDFFile

    try {
        val pdfUrl = URL(strPdfUrl)
        val urlConnection = pdfUrl.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        if (urlConnection.responseCode == 200) {
            //file input is from the url
            inputStream = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream)
            lenghtOfFile = urlConnection.contentLength
            localPDFFile = File(localPdfDirectory, pdfFileName.value!!)
            fileOut = FileOutputStream(localPDFFile)

            //here’s the download code
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var total: Long = 0

            while (true) {
                // If coroutine is cancelled
                // a CancellationException will be thrown here
                // Do not more work then necesarry
                coroutineContext.ensureActive()

                val length = inputStream.read(buffer)
                if (length <= 0) break
                total += length.toLong()
                _currProgress.postValue( (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile).toInt()  )
                fileOut.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
        }

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("PdfViewerViewModel - downloadFile Error: ${e.message}")
        localPdfFile?.delete() // remove partially downloaded file
        localPDFFile = null
    } catch (e1: CancellationException) {
        Log.e("PdfViewerViewModel - downloadFile CancellationException: ${e1.message}")
        localPdfFile?.delete() // remove partially downloaded file
        localPdfFile = null
    finally {
        try {
            inputStream?.close()
            fileOut?.apply {
                flush()
                close()
            }
        } catch (e1: IOException) { //do nothing here }
    }
    return localPDFFile
}
```

Kindly regards
Frank

@Update 10.04.2020
Implementation with coroutineContext.ensureActive() and catching the exception

Comment: It won't leak because you're cleaning up in the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there also a way to to some extra work on cancellation? For example remove the current partial download?

Comment: Yeah, inside the `finally` block. You can wrap it in `if (!isActive) { }`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I learned to better use ensureActive() in your coroutine because this will stop your coroutine by throwing a CancellationException.
For everyone who is interested take a look at this [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629)

Comment: That won’t help with doing cleanup in finally because you want to run code when it is NOT active.

Comment: Hmmmm - as you can see from the code above I catch the CancellationException that is thrown from ensureActivity() and cleanup the partially downloaded file. That has also be done when an IOException accords. And in finally I only close the streams because when everything works fine I would return the downloaded file.
Or do you think I should remove the catcher and check the file size of the downloaded file and remove it when not fully downloaded?